# Cannot install shfl in python

Tags: python-3.x, pip, anaconda, conda, federated-learning

I am trying to use shfl python library. When I import shfl, I get the error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'shfl'`, and apparently I cannot install it.

I have used three following commands and all are unsuccessful with the errors I mention below (I use conda). My python version is `3.10.12`. My conda version is `23.5.0`, and my pip version is `23.1.2`.

1- `pip install shfl`(based on [this link](https://github.com/officialarijit/Federated-Learning-Framework/blob/main/install.md)) ---> I get this error:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement shfl (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for shfl
```

2- `pip install shfl==0.1.0` (based on [this link](https://package.wiki/shfl)) ---> I get this error:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement shfl==0.1.0 (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for shfl==0.1.0
```

3- `conda install -c conda-forge shfl` (because I use conda environment) ---> I get this error:

```
PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

  - shfl
```

Comment: There is no `shfl` at https://pypi.org/project/shfl/ so you cannot install it with `pip`. There is no `shfl` at https://anaconda.org/search?q=shfl so you cannot install it with `conda`. Mentioned site sherpa.ai points to https://github.com/sherpaai but it doesn't have public repositories. I would be very afraid of installing code that has such mistakes in its docs; it's probably unofficial and buggy. Are you sure you want to install it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that there is no 'shfl' package in PyPI.
[Search from PyPI 'shfl'](https://pypi.org/search/?q=shfl)

So, you should 'git clone' from
[Federated-Learning-Framework repo](https://github.com/officialarijit/Federated-Learning-Framework.git)

Then, pip install /any/location/cloned/directory